# Azure DevOps - Sprint (Capacity Data) in Power BI

Tags: azure-devops, sprint, capacity-planning

We have the requirement to load the capacity data which we mentioned in the sprint in the azure Devops for the various analysis, can you help me with the solution how we can pull data and put it into the power BI.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure DevOps - Sprint (Capacity Data) in Power BI

I am afraid there is no such way to connect Azure sprint capacity data into PowerBI at this moment.

You could take a look below similar threas below:

- [Is it possible to connect Azure sprint capacity data into
  PowerBI?](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Is-it-possible-to-connect-Azure-sprint-capacity-data-into/m-p/1138785#M517766)
- [How to fetch Azure sprint capacity to power bi.](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/How-to-fetch-Azure-sprint-capacity-to-power-bi/m-p/1445106)

Instead, you may have to use [Rest API Capacities - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/Capacities/Get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) to  get a team member's capacity.

Comment: HI, I got the REST API from where we can collect the information but while trying with different teams and even try for the different projects as well. for all, I am getting the below error while executing into the WEB, Not sure what I am missing but something needs to be set for the REST API? Error - {"count":1,"value":{"Message":"The request is invalid."}}